# How to display the dynamic controlled form in the next row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, dynamic-forms

I want to display the page like this:

[image]

But when I want to make it as a dynamic form with this jQuery/JavaScript method to make a dynamic controlled input form:

https://jsfiddle.net/aaki/hMJEy/1/

It become like this:

[image]

May I know how to adjust the layout with it:

Here is the code:

```
<form onSubmit={this.addTodo}>
 <div class="multi-field-wrapper">
  <div class="multi-fields">
   <div class="multi-field">
     <Button
      type="submit"
      className="btn show-modal"
      onClick={() =>
       this.setState({
        showModal: !showModal
       })
      }
     >
     Send Email
     </Button>

     <Button
       type="submit"
       className="btn show-portal"
       onClick={() =>
        this.setState({
         showPortal: !showPortal
        })
       }
      >
      Send SMS
      </Button>

      <Modal
        header="Send Email"
        open={showModal}
        onClose={() =>
         this.setState({
         showModal: false
         })
        }
       >
      <h1>Send Email</h1>
      <p>Send Email</p>
      <div className="form-group">
      <Col md="6">
      <Label htmlFor="text-input">Email</Label>
      </Col>
      <Col xs="12" md="9">
      <Input type="text" id="text-input" name="text-input" placeholder="Email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleEmailChange} required/>
      </Col>
      </div>

      <div className="form-group">
      <Col md="6">
      <Label htmlFor="text-input">Subject</Label>
      </Col>
      <Col xs="12" md="9">
      <Input type="text" id="text-input" name="text-input" placeholder="device alert" value="{{this.state.topic}} alert" required/>
      </Col>
      </div>

      <div className="form-group">
      <Col md="6">
      <Label htmlFor="text-input">Message</Label>
      </Col>
      <Col xs="12" md="9">
      <textarea className="textarea" id="text-input" name="text-input" placeholder="Message" value="Hey there, {{this.state.topic}} was {{last_value}} at {{trigger_timestamp|timestampformat('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur')}}." required/>
       </Col>
       </div>

       <div className="form-group">
       <Col md="6">
       </Col>
       <Col xs="12" md="9">
       </Col>
       </div>
       <div className="form-group">
       <Col md="6">
       </Col>
       <Col xs="12" md="9">
       </Col>
       </div>
       <div className="form-group">
       <Col md="6">
       </Col>
       <Col xs="12" md="9">
       </Col>
       </div>
       <div className="form-group">
       <Col md="6">
       </Col>
       <Col xs="12" md="9">
       </Col>
       </div>
       <div className="form-group">
       <Col md="6">
       </Col>
       <Col xs="12" md="9">
       </Col>
       </div>

       <FormGroup row>
        <Col md="3">
        </Col>
       <Col xs="12" md="9">
       <span className="icon is-small"></span>
       <Button type="submit" size="sm" color="primary"><i className="fas fa-dot-circle"></i> Submit</Button>
       </Col>
       </FormGroup>
       <span className="icon is-small"></span>

       </Modal>

       <Portal
        open={showPortal}
        header="Send SMS"
        onClose={() =>
        this.setState({
         showPortal: false
         })
        }
       >
       <h1>Send SMS</h1>
        <p>Send SMS</p>

        <div className="form-group">
        <Col md="6">
        <Label htmlFor="text-input">Country</Label>
        </Col>
        <Col xs="12" md="9">
        <Input type="text" id="text-input" name="text-input" placeholder="+6 Malaysia" value="+6 Malaysia" required/>
        </Col>
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
         <Col md="6">
          <Label htmlFor="text-input">Phone number</Label>
         </Col>
         <Col xs="12" md="9">
         <Input type="text" id="text-input" name="text-input" placeholder="Phone number" value={this.state.contact} onChange={this.handleContactChange} required/>
          </Col>
         </div>

         <div className="form-group">
          <Col md="6">
           <Label htmlFor="text-input">Message</Label>
          </Col>
          <Col xs="12" md="9">
          <textarea className="textarea" id="text-input" name="text-input" placeholder="Message" value="Hey there, {{this.state.topic}} was {{last_value}} at {{trigger_timestamp|timestampformat('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur')}}." required/>
          </Col>
         </div>

         <div className="form-group">
          <Col md="6">
          </Col>
          <Col xs="12" md="9">
          </Col>
         </div>
         <div className="form-group">
          <Col md="6">
          </Col>
          <Col xs="12" md="9">
          </Col>
         </div>
         <div className="form-group">
          <Col md="6">
          </Col>
          <Col xs="12" md="9">
          </Col>
         </div>
         <div className="form-group">
          <Col md="6">
          </Col>
          <Col xs="12" md="9">
          </Col>
         </div>
         <div className="form-group">
          <Col md="6">
          </Col>
          <Col xs="12" md="9">
          </Col>
         </div>

         <FormGroup row>
          <Col md="3">
          </Col>
          <Col xs="12" md="9">
          <span className="icon is-small"></span>
          <Button type="submit" size="sm" color="primary"><i className="fas fa-dot-circle"></i> Submit</Button>
           </Col>
           </FormGroup>
           </Portal>
           <div className="is-small">
            <select onChange={this.handleTopicChange} required>
             <option>Select topic</option>
              {
               this.state.topicData.map((item, index) =>
               <option key={item.topic} value={this.state.topic}>{item.topic}</option>
              )
             }
            </select>
           </div>
           <input type="text" placeholder="temperature" value="temperature" disabled/>
           <div>is</div>
           <div className="select is-small">
           <select id="selColor" value={this.state.selectedOption} onChange={this.handleChange}>
           <option selected value="equal">Equal to</option>
           <option value="notequal">Not equal to</option>
           <option value="greater_than">Greater than</option>
           <option value="smaller_than">Less than</option>
           <option value="goe">Greater than or equal to</option>
           <option value="loe">Less than or equal to</option>
          </select>
         </div>
         <span></span>
         <input id="test1" className="hideable" type="text" value={this.state.equal} onChange={this.handleEqualChange} />
         <input id="test2" className="hideable" type="text" value={this.state.notequal} onChange={this.handleNotEqualChange} />
         <input id="test3" className="hideable" type="text" value={this.state.greater_than} onChange={this.handleGreaterThanChange} />
         <input id="test4" className="hideable" type="text" value={this.state.smaller_than} onChange={this.handleSmallerThanChange} />
         <input id="test5" className="hideable" type="text" value={this.state.goe} onChange={this.handleGOEChange} />
         <input id="test6" className="hideable" type="text" value={this.state.loe} onChange={this.handleLOEChange} />
         <span></span>
         <i className="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
         <button type="button" className="remove-field">Remove</button>
         <button type="button" className="add-field">Add field</button>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

I have tried put the "multifield-wrapper" classname before the "form" then the display can be like the first image but the problem is it cannot add the dynamic form when click the 'Add field' button and it does nothing. May I know how to solve this problem? If you know how to do it can you provided the example code with the explanation too? It is because I still learning how to do it with React, thank you.

**Updated code**

I was able to put all the text box in a row by putting the javascript inside the form but the problem is when I add one more row the next row the text box display was like this as shown in the 2nd image below:

Here is the code:

```
<form onSubmit={this.addTodo}> 
 <div className="row">
  <div className="multi-field-wrapper">
   <div className="multi-fields">
    <div className="multi-field">
     <div className="col-md-2 is-small">
      <select onChange={this.handleTopicChange} required>
       <option>Select topic</option>
        {
         this.state.topicData.map((item, index) =>
          <option key={item.topic} value={this.state.topic}>{item.topic}</option>
         )
        }
      </select>
     </div>
     <input className="col-md-2" type="text" placeholder="temperature" value="temperature" disabled/>
      <div className="col-md-1">is</div>
       <div className="select col-md-2 is-small">
        <select id="selColor" value={this.state.selectedOption} onChange={this.handleChange}>
         <option value="equal">Equal to</option>
         <option value="notequal">Not equal to</option>
         <option value="greater_than">Greater than</option>
         <option value="smaller_than">Less than</option>
         <option value="goe">Greater than or equal to</option>
         <option value="loe">Less than or equal to</option>
        </select>
       </div>
       <input id="test1" className="hideable col-md-1" type="text" value={this.state.equal} onChange={this.handleEqualChange} />
       <input id="test2" className="hideable col-md-1" type="text" value={this.state.notequal} onChange={this.handleNotEqualChange} />
       <input id="test3" className="hideable col-md-1" type="text" value={this.state.greater_than} onChange={this.handleGreaterThanChange} />
       <input id="test4" className="hideable col-md-1" type="text" value={this.state.smaller_than} onChange={this.handleSmallerThanChange} />
       <input id="test5" className="hideable col-md-1" type="text" value={this.state.goe} onChange={this.handleGOEChange} />
       <input id="test6" className="hideable col-md-1" type="text" value={this.state.loe} onChange={this.handleLOEChange} />
       <button type="button" className="remove-field col-md-2">Remove</button>      
       <button type="button" className="add-field col-md-2">Add field</button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </form>
```

The first row is ok:

[image]

When add the next row the display was like this:

[image]

May I know how to solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep all the div in one row like

```
<div class = "row">
   <div class ="col-lg-12">
      //put your all child div here which you wants to keep in one row and properly divide the col-lg-12 for every child div
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, I tried ur code it cannot be done & the display of the text box merge with each others now...

Comment: put your text box inside <div class="col-lg-12"><div class="col-lg-4"><input type="text"></div><div class="col-lg-4"><input type="text"></div></div> separate-separate

Comment: import bootstrap version 3 then it will work

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Answer (score 0):

you can use form-row class

```
<div className="form-row">
```

if you want two elements in same row

```
  <div className="form-row">
  <div className="form-group col-md-6">
    <label >email</label>
    <input type="text"/>
</div>
  <div className="form-group col-md-6">
    <label>message</label>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
</div>
```

if you want one input in one row

```
 <div className="form-group col-md-12">
<label >email</label>
<input type="text"/>
```

hope you it will help

Comment: it is still the same because all the text input was showing on the right corner only...so it makes all the text input merge with each other if using your code too.